# How to optimize App in ReactJS on re-renders

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I have to optimize this App here, How can I implement or pass onDelete to Child so I don't have new function on each re-render? (I am not allowed to change the child component)

```
function App() {
  const [names, setNames] = React.useState(["iamfirst", "methesecond"]);

  const onDelete = useCallback( (index:number) => {
    setNames((prev) => prev.filter((_, i) => i !== index));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {names.map((name, index) => (
        <Child
          key={index}
          name={name}
          onChange={onNameChange}
          onDelete={()=>onDelete(index)}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Why can't you change the child? This is a pretty easy fix if you can, but without changing the child it'll be a hacky workaround

Comment: Idk that's what the problem says...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
onDelete={this.onDelete}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 onDelete={onDelete.bind(null, index)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your child components will be re-rendered anyway when you delete it because you are passing index to the key when you delete 1 item from the array, you update all children because a key was changed. To avoid re-rendering, all of your children should have IDs, and you will rely on this. Also, you should not have arrow functions passed directly like in your example `onDelete={()=>onDelete(index)}`.

So, your solution should be refactored to meet these requirements, and there is no way without `Child` modifying.